# Entity Framework map same table that exists in two databases

Tags: entity-framework-4

What options are available to correctly map the following using Entity Framework:

Database 1 tables:
Foo, Foo_Assets, Assets

Database 2 tables:
Bar, Bar_Assets, Assets

I have considered mapping Bar, Bar_Assets, Assets as SQL views, or using a different db context when loading these tables from Database 2.

The challenge is that although Foo, Bar and their _Assets tables can be treated independently, both databases have an Assets table. How can these tables be correctly mapped to the Asset entity?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 databases, you will have 2 edmx files. Just having a different name in the edmx for Assets table will work. This way you can ensure that there are no clashes.

Comment: Sorry, Should have stated I am using Code First so no EDMX files.

Comment: I ended up making the following changes which seem to have done the trick.
- Created 2 DBContexts for database1 and database2 - both of these referencing the Assets IDbSet
- Using Ninject Controller Factory, bind correct DBContext to Foo and Bar Repositories